# How to delete data from database and UI using react.js and axios?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am trying to delete data from my app both in the database and UI, but I am a

bit confused on how to request this action from react.js using axios. I have

created a method call which I assigned to an event handler on the elements

'delete' button within my react app but continue to get a message of 'null' in

the terminal. I suppose this is the app telling me that it cannot find the

element I am trying to delete and would greatly appreciate it if someone could

point me in the right direction or give me some pointers on how to fix errors I

may have made along the way.

Below is my react code

```
  state = {
```

title: '',

```
body: '',

posts: []
```

}

deleteBlogPosts = () => {

```
axios.delete(`/api/delete`)

.then((response) => {

  console.log(`${response} request deleted`)

})

.catch((err) => {

  console.log(err.response)


})
```

}

displayBlogPosts = (posts) => {

```
if(!posts.length) return null

return posts.map((post, index) => (

  <div className='blog' key={index}>
    <h1>{post.title}</h1>

    <h5>{post.body}</h5>
    <button onClick={this.deleteBlogPosts()}>delete</button>

  </div>

))
```

}

MY API file with the endpoints

```
router.delete('/delete', (req, res) => {

Blog.findOneAndRemove({

    _id: req.params.Id

}, (err, data) => {

    console.log(data)

    if(err) {

        res.status(500).json({

            msg: 'Houston we have a problem'

        })

        return

    }return res.json({

        msg: 'Data was received'

    })
})
```

})

Comment: Try so simplify your code example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey everyone thanks for those who attempted to help. Shortly after posting, I realized that I had unnecessary parameters within my 'delete' endpoint. I also found out that I failed to include the ID in the endpoint URL. **SO** happy that I got it taken care of.